# Creating 3D road like effect in windows 8

Tags: windows-runtime, directx, winrt-xaml

How to create a 3d road like effect in windows 8 using Direct X & Xaml. Can anyone help me or guide me to create a road like effect in windows 8. I am attaching something similar sample image along with this.

Or If it is possible to repressed the same in xaml & C#. Guide me in that way. Because I am more confirmable in that technology. I am not an active developer of Direct X. Also I a not looking for a "Do that for me" approach. I need only guidelines or some sample reference that help me to implement the same.

[image: Here is the image URl]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, this is going to be tricky. I want to point you to the MatrixTransform. The only way to accomplish what you are wanting to do. It's no small feat. Some of the capabilities of the MatrixTransform have been wrapped in a helper class called ProjectionPlane, but it doesn't give you the pinch look your graphic indicates. Given the out-of-the-box ProjectionPanel, I think something like this is the best you will be able to accomplish.

[image]

Remember, the MatrixTransform can do it. But it's going to be some work. Work, like I am sure, it took to create the graph you are wanting to emulate. Awesome doesn't come free.

```
<Grid Background="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="728" />
        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="BackgroundGrid" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="0,0,0,-282" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform ScaleX="0.75" ScaleY="0.75" TranslateY="-250"/>
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
        <Grid.Projection>
            <PlaneProjection RotationX="-29"/>
        </Grid.Projection><Rectangle Fill="Gainsboro" Grid.Column="0" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Gainsboro" Grid.Column="2" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Gainsboro" Grid.Column="4" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Gainsboro" Grid.Column="6" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Gainsboro" Grid.Column="8" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Gainsboro" Grid.Column="10" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Gainsboro" Grid.Column="12" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Gainsboro" Grid.Column="14" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Gainsboro" Grid.Column="16" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Gainsboro" Grid.Column="18" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Gainsboro" Grid.Column="20" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Gray" Grid.Column="1" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Gray" Grid.Column="3" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Gray" Grid.Column="5" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Gray" Grid.Column="7" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Gray" Grid.Column="9" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Gray" Grid.Column="11" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Gray" Grid.Column="13" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Gray" Grid.Column="15" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Gray" Grid.Column="17" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Gray" Grid.Column="19" />
    </Grid>
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ForegroundGrid"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="0,0,0,-282">
        <ScrollViewer.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform ScaleX="0.75" ScaleY="0.75" TranslateY="-230"/>
        </ScrollViewer.RenderTransform>
        <ScrollViewer.Projection>
            <PlaneProjection RotationX="-29"/>
        </ScrollViewer.Projection>
        <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Ellipse">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="50" />
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="50" />
                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Green" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Ellipse Margin="0,1040,0,0" Grid.Column="0" />
        <Ellipse Margin="0,1240,0,0" Grid.Column="3" />
        <Ellipse Margin="0,550,0,0" Grid.Column="4" />
        <Ellipse Margin="0,350,0,0" Grid.Column="4" />
        <Ellipse Margin="0,600,0,0" Grid.Column="7" />
        <Ellipse Margin="0,1450,0,0" Grid.Column="11" />
        <Ellipse Margin="0,650,0,0" Grid.Column="13" />
        <Ellipse Margin="0,1150,0,0" Grid.Column="13" />
        <Ellipse Margin="0,450,0,0" Grid.Column="14" />
        <Ellipse Margin="0,1250,0,0" Grid.Column="17" />
        <Ellipse Margin="0,550,0,0" Grid.Column="18" />
    </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Grid x:Name="BottomGrid" Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Fill="Orange" Grid.Column="0" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Orange" Grid.Column="2" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Orange" Grid.Column="4" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Orange" Grid.Column="6" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Orange" Grid.Column="8" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Orange" Grid.Column="10" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Orange" Grid.Column="12" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Orange" Grid.Column="14" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Orange" Grid.Column="16" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Orange" Grid.Column="18" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Orange" Grid.Column="20" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Chocolate" Grid.Column="1" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Chocolate" Grid.Column="3" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Chocolate" Grid.Column="5" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Chocolate" Grid.Column="7" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Chocolate" Grid.Column="9" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Chocolate" Grid.Column="11" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Chocolate" Grid.Column="13" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Chocolate" Grid.Column="15" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Chocolate" Grid.Column="17" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Chocolate" Grid.Column="19" />
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="0,0,-1266,-950">
                <Grid.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="Ellipse">
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="50" />
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="50" />
                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Green" />
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
                    </Style>
                </Grid.Resources>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform ScaleX="0.75" ScaleY="0.75" TranslateY="-250"/>
                </Grid.RenderTransform>
                <Grid.Projection>
                    <PlaneProjection RotationX="-29"/>
                </Grid.Projection>
                <Ellipse Margin="0,040,0,0" Grid.Column="0" />
                <Ellipse Margin="0,240,0,0" Grid.Column="3" />
                <Ellipse Margin="0,550,0,0" Grid.Column="4" />
                <Ellipse Margin="0,350,0,0" Grid.Column="4" />
                <Ellipse Margin="0,600,0,0" Grid.Column="7" />
                <Ellipse Margin="0,450,0,0" Grid.Column="11" />
                <Ellipse Margin="0,650,0,0" Grid.Column="13" />
                <Ellipse Margin="0,250,0,0" Grid.Column="13" />
                <Ellipse Margin="0,450,0,0" Grid.Column="14" />
                <Ellipse Margin="0,250,0,0" Grid.Column="17" />
                <Ellipse Margin="0,550,0,0" Grid.Column="18" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

You'll likely have the best luck doing this as DX and not XAML. But if you don't know DX then you can hit the XAML solution which will be awesome when you get it. I am sure.

Best of luck!

Comment: Great done.. Jerry. You are awesome... :) But my worry is still it looks like 2D..

Comment: It totally looks 2D, man. There's one other thing you can do. My assumption is that the items on the "road" need to move smoothly down the road. But if you don't need that, if they can snap to their new location, then their place on the axis could include the scale location and skew. What I mean is, you can use a 3D graphic as the background, then the tokens in the front are just going to the correct place based on the user clicking up and down. It's the smooth scrolling of the items to roll down the road that made this difficult. If they snap, you could do this pretty low-tech.

Comment: For the sake of information, there is no 3D implementation for WinRT-XAML like there is in Silverlight. Silverlight could do what you want - not easily, but it could do it. WinRT doesn't have 3D except for what developers can accomplish with the MatrixTransform. Since the Windows "style" is flat, this isn't really a problem, but lots of SL developers often assume they will find 3D caps like they had in SL when it's just not there.